# How to replace depreciated UILocalNotification and add UNNotificationAction in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilocalnotification

I have created a scheduled notification in ViewController.swift and need two actions to be added to this notification. One that says "Call", and the other that says "Cancel". How can I add these actions in ViewController.swift? Here is the part of the code that has the function for firing my notification in my ViewController.swift:

```
func notificationFires(){

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    // 2
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.fireDate = datePicker.date

    // 3
    if textField.text == "" {

        notification.alertBody = "You have a call right now!"

    }
    else{

        notification.alertBody = self.textField.text

    }
    // 4
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
    // 5
    // 6
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    // 7
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)



    func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Recived: notification")



        if cancelled == true{
            print("cancelled happened")

        }
        func cancelNotify(){
            cancelled = true
            UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)

    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for: http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/

Comment: +Frankie I have tried that website and I run into many errors

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You are scheduling a local notification then why are you checking remoteNotifications?

Comment: +Adeel that was just something on the side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used notifications in iOS 10 yet, so I went ahead and figured it out as a learning experience for myself, now I can pass it on to you.

`UILocalNotification` is depreciated in iOS 10 and replaced by the `UserNotifications` framework.

In your `AppDelegate` get authorization from the user to show notifications and set up the centers delegate with `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound];
    center.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
        (granted, error) in
        if !granted {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Present the notification to the user:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Play sound and show alert to the user
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}
```

Handling the actions:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // Determine the user action
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("Dismiss Action")
    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
        print("Default")
    case "foo":
        print("foo")
    case "bar":
        print("bar")
    default:
        print("Unknown action")
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Do this wherever you want to setup all actions and categories for all notifications in your app.  Because they're assigned to the center, not the notification itself:

```
func setupActions() {

    //create first action
    let foo = UNNotificationAction(
        identifier: "foo",
        title: "foo"
    )

    //create second action
    let bar = UNNotificationAction(
        identifier: "bar",
        title: "bar",
        options: [.destructive]
    )

    //put the two actions into a category and give it an identifier
    let cat = UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: "cat",
        actions: [foo, bar],
        intentIdentifiers: []
    )

    //add the category to the notification center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([cat])
}
```

And finally creating the actual notification:

```
func setupNotification() {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    content.title = "Hello!"
    content.body = "A message"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    //make sure to assign the correct category identifier
    content.categoryIdentifier = "cat"

    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "hello", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print("theError \(theError)")
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to `import UserNotifications` in each class utilizing these functions.

More info: [User Notifications documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications).

Comment: It won't let me use `self` for the `center.delegate`

Comment: the class needs to implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

Comment: +Frankie how do I do that?

Comment: I figured it out another way but I'll just give you the check